# Find specific value between tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to let me find a value from `@update` line (between opening `/*@file` and closing `@*/`

Example code:

```
/*@file
######################################################
@package        Webapp
@title          your_title
@version        1.0
@tags           tag1,tag2
@lines          215
@created        2020/04/03 20:42:49
@updated        2020/03/03 20:44:49
@description
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
######################################################
@*/
```

In this case, the desired value is `2020/03/03 20:44:49`

I finished my attempts at

```
[\/][*]@file\n([\S\s]*?)update([\S\s]*?)[@][*][\/]
```

And my JS code

```
currentText.replace(/[\/][*]@file\n([\S\s]*?)update([\S\s]*?)[@][*][\/]/g, "SOME TEXT");
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a capture group:

```
/\/\*@file[^]*?@updated[ \t]*(.+)[^]*?@\*\//
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zP8em4/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\/\*@file`: Match text `/*@file`
- `[^]*?`: Match 0 or of any characters (including newlines) (lazy)
- `@updated[ \t]*`: Match text `@updated` followed by 0 or more space/tabs
- `(.+)`: Match and capture value we want to grab
- `[^]*?`: Match 0 or of any characters (including newlines) (lazy)
- `@\*\/`: Match text `@*/`

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any solution to update@update value? Regex looks good, now I have a problem with the js function.

Comment: Capture group #1 will give you value that you want `2020/03/03 20:44:49`

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be right

```
const Alt = currentText.replace(/ /g, '').substring((currentText.replace(/ /g, '').indexOf('@updated')+8),(currentText.replace(/ /g, '').indexOf('@updated')+26))
Alt = Alt.substring(0,10) + ' ' + Alt.substring(11, 18)
console.log(Alt)
```